# CVD MoS2 always get many particles/stuff on the surface, what is problem?

Tags: materials

The $\ce{MoO3}$ and $\ce{SiO2}$ substrate is placed in the center of furnace and sulfur boat is in the upstream out of the furnace. In a general growth:

- $\approx \pu{2 mg}$ $\ce{MoO3}$ and $\approx \pu{200 mg}$ sulfur is used (PTAS as promoter)
- Gas: $\ce{Ar}$ $\pu{80 sccm}$ (sccm for [standard cubic centimetre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCCM_(flow_unit)))
- Growth time: $\pu{10 min}$
- growth temp: $\pu{650 ^\circ{}\text{C}}$

Bellow are the images I got (both AFM and optical images), many stuff/particles on the $\ce{MoS2}$ surface.

What is problem and how should I change for set up/receipt? I have tried with different growth time (1,4,7,10 min), increase distance between $\ce{MoO3}$ source and $\ce{SiO2}$ substrate, change $\ce{MoO3}$ amount ($\pu{1 mg}$, $\pu{5 mg}$) but still I get the same results.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Do these photos illustrate the situation prior/after the intended deposit?  Is your sort left to right, top to bottom? If so (or not), add labels and explain if they are taken in sequence in the question.  In micro photography, the use a scale of reference is very helpful, too; just to get an idea of the absolute and relative dimensions. What are the greater plates in the photo?  Not clearly stated.  So, you do worry about the almost black speckles in the top right photo? The black speckles are not evenly distributed on the small plates exposed.

Comment: Thanks @Buttonwood for the correction.